# RegisterName UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, canvas, storyboard

I have a WPF application with a grid and inside the grid I have a canvas control.
I also created a user control that I add to the canvas control.
I am creating a storyboard to animate that user control, but when I call myStoryboard.Begin(myUserControl) I always get the error: myControl name cannot be found in the name scope of 'ScoreBoard.Controls.ucWindow' (that is my control class).

So I was looking for some solution and I found that I need to Create a NameScope so that
Storyboards can be used and I need to register the name of my control.

I already tried both things but I still get that error.

I tried to create a NameScope for the window and for the canvas

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
//NameScope.SetNameScope(myCanvas, new NameScope());
```

and tried to register the name:

```
//myCanvas.RegisterName(myControl.Name, myUserControl);
this.RegisterName(myUserControl.Name, myUserControl);

myCanvas.Children.Add(myUserControl);
```

Does anyone know if I am missing something?

Thanks in advance,

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found a possible solution, when I was calling Storyboard.begin I was using Storyboard.SetTargetName, instead of Storyboard.SetTargetName I used Storyboard.SetTarget and now my code is working as I expected.

Regards,

Alberto